# When importing data from Excel spreadsheets using library(readxl), am I able to import a subset of columns based on name instead of position?

Tags: r, readxl

I currently use the "range" option to only import the first 10 columns, then I keep the columns I need.

```
df <- read_excel("workbook1.xlsx", sheet = "SHEET1", range = cell_cols(1:10) )
```

Is there a way to import by column name?

EDIT: I'm importing the columns from about 70 different workbooks, and the columns are in slightly different locations in each one, but have the same names.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is an approach that would work.

This reads the full excel file, subsets to the columns you want after it has been read in, and row binds them into one big dataframe with an `file` column denoting which file the data came from.

```
library(tidyverse)

list.files(path ='path_to_files', full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  set_names() %>%
  map_dfr(.id = 'file', .f = function(x){
    
    read_excel(x, sheet = "SHEET1") %>%
      select(Columns, You, Want, To, Select)
    
  })
```

Or the base R equivalent

```
files_to_read <- list.files(path ='path_to_files', full.names = TRUE)
columns_to_select <- c('c1', 'c2')
  
list_of_dfs <- lapply(files_to_read, function(x){
  
  read_excel(x, sheet = "SHEET1")[c(columns_to_select)]
  
})

one_df <- do.call('rbind', list_of_dfs)
```